# How do I move a support post for a 4x5 stair landing?

Tags: post, support

The back door of my church has a stair landing above it that is supported by two 4x4 posts. One of the posts is in the path of the door and people are always running into it. I want to move this post over 12 inches to create a clear walkway. The structure above is simply an enclosed stair landing (4' x 5') that attaches to the newer second story. (Picture a 50"x48" rectangle sticking out from the building.) It is made as follows: On the 50" stair side: 2- 2x12x58 beams that sit on the 8" block header of the first story and a 4x4 post on a concrete slab. The other 50" side is 2- 2x12x50 beams that do not attach to the building side but rest on a 4x4 post on a concrete slab. The 48" side next to the building is 1- 2x12x48 attached to the wood frame of the second story. The problem side is 1- 2x12x48 and 1- 2x12x40 that are nailed into the 50" sides and bracketed to the 4x4 posts.
My thought is to bolt a 2x8x66 to the existing outside 2x12x48 with 1/2" lag bolts every 8" and bracket it to the top of a new 4x4. I would also attach a hanger bracket to the building side that is currently NOT supported. Then I would cut off the existing 4x4 that is in the way of the door.
Does this sound like it would work?

Comment: A simple photo would have saved you a whole lot of typing and us a whole lot of eyebrow furrowing. :)

Answer (score 1):

In a commercial building, you have a duty of care to your clients.

The only place to get this kind of advice is from an accredited source, such as a professional engineer or architect.